# how to traverse all the characters in the the string?

Tags: python

I've a question to check conditional statements which should traverse all the characters and meet the condition. any idea to do it?
question is: Have the function `SimpleSymbols(str)` take the `str` parameter being passed and determine if it is an acceptable sequence by either returning the string `true` or `false`. The `str` parameter will be composed of `+` and `=` symbols with several characters between them (ie. ++d+===+c++==a) and for the string to be true each letter must be surrounded by a `+` symbol. So the string to the left would be false. The string will not be empty and will have at least one letter.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please don't use this website to do your homework.

Comment: this not the homework i'm stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC:

```
def SimpleSymbols(string):
    for i, char in enumerate(string):
        if char.isalpha():
            try:
                if string[i-1] != '+' or string[i+1] != '+':
                    return False
            except KeyError:
                return False

    return True
```